# How to set up a Phoenix route that takes multiple params in the query string

Tags: routes, phoenix-framework

I am looking to generate a route in Phoenix that will accept 2 query params.

`get "/items?id=:id&action=:action", ActionController, :index_by`

But I get the following error:

```
(Plug.Router.InvalidSpecError) :identifier in routes must be made of letters, numbers and underscores
```

I noticed that when I remove the second parameter that it compiles just fine, so I am guessing this has something to do with the delimiter `&` to separate out the params in the query string.

Is there another way to specify multiple params like that to differentiate the route?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Route definitions are mainly for 'clean urls' since it matches on the request path (without the query string).

With that in mind, you can define your route like this

```
get("item/:id/:action", ActionController, :index_by)
#Or
get("/items", ActionController, :index_by)
```

The first route definition will capture `id` and `action` from the request path e.g GET /items/1/edit will give you `%{"id"=>1, "action"=>"edit"}` in your params.

The second will capture `id` and `action` from the query string. e.g `GET "/items?id=1&action=delete"` will give you `%{"id"=>1, "action"=>"delete"}` in your params

Note that, the second route definition, unlike the first, does not enforce the presence of either `id` or `action` in the query string so you are not guaranteed those paramaters will be available in your params.